# Terraform EC2 instance does not appear in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I've just begun using Terraform and I ran `terraform apply` on a very simple template. This is the entire content of `main.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "marcellusWallace" {
    ami = "ami-2d39803a"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"

    tags {
        Name = "terraform-example"
    }
}
```

The output from Terraform says that the instance has been created. The state says an instance exists.

```
Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

The problem is, I cannot see it in the AWS EC2 console. Also, the instance is missing in the output of `aws ec2 describe-instances`.

**Where is the instance?**

Comment: I've checked that there is no search filter in the EC2 console. Have I missed any other obvious checks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`main.tf` is using `us-east-1`.

AWS Console and CLI were using `us-west-2`.

How embarassing.

Comment: that's a beginner fault. :-) By the way, if you can't find the instance or other resources, use [resource group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/creating-a-resource-group.html) feature to search it in all regions.

Comment: Thanks @BMW, I did not know I could do that.

Answer (score 2):

try changing the region on top right .

You need to check the region on which you've created your ec2 instance.

you probably are trying to find it somewhere else.

Comment: Please don't repeat the OP's answer